# Amazon App Store - App Publishing

Tags: amazon-appstore

```
I Want to Upload an App Which Uses Google Map Api and also C2DM Push
```

Notification Service and Gps. What I should Change to Upload My App into Amazon App Store. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Because the Kindle devices, and some devices where you can install the Amazon Appstore, won't have the Google Mobile Services you would need to replace those with the corresponding Amazon services and APIs from https://developer.amazon.com/sdk.html